# Why can I seal a class implementing an interface but cant seal a member?

Tags: .net, inheritance, interface, virtual, sealed

Given this interface

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string Method1();
}
```

Why is this valid

```
public sealed class InheretedFromInterfaceSealed: IMyInterface
{
    public string Method1()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But this isnt

```
public class InheretedFromInterfaceWithSomeSealed: IMyInterface
{
    public sealed string Method1()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And yet it is a valid scenario for an abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract string Method1();
}
public class InheretedFromAbstractWithSomeSealed: AbstractClass
{
    public sealed override string Method1()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because every method is by default sealed, unless it's virtual, or unless you don't say `sealed` on something that's already virtual and that you're overriding.

Comment: the thing that got me was I was converting from an abstract class to an interface and marking a member as sealed is valid in the abstract class scenario. See edit.

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah, I blanked out for a moment on this too, until I realized what was happening. :)

Answer (score 1):

Every method in a class is sealed (`NotOverridable` in VB.NET) by default, unless you specifically declare it as `virtual` (`Overridable` in VB.NET).

As you've said, this is *not* the case with classes. You have to specifically indicate that you want to forbid inheriting from a class using `sealed` (or `NotInheritable` in VB.NET).

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder that interface methods in C# cannot be `sealed`.

Consider the following code:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}
class Base : IFoo
{
    public void Bar() { Console.WriteLine("Base.Bar"); }
}
class Derived : Base, IFoo
{
    public new void Bar() { Console.WriteLine("Derived.Bar"); }
}
```

And then, if we have `var d = new Derived()`, we'll have:

- `d.Bar()` writes `Derived.Bar`
- `((Base)d).Bar()` writes `Base.Bar`
- `((IFoo)d).Bar()` writes `Derived.Bar`
- `((IFoo)(Base)d).Bar()` writes `Derived.Bar`

The interface method `Bar` is overridden by the derived class. The method that is `sealed` is **not *the* interface method**, but a method of `Base`.

That is to say, an implicit implementation

```
class ImplicitImpl : IFoo
{
    public void Bar() { Blah; }
}
```

should be considered as the following semantically equivalent explicit implementation:

```
class ImplicitImplEquiv : IFoo
{
    public void Bar() { Blah; }
    void IFoo.Bar() { this.Bar(); }
}
```

If a derived class of `ImplicitImplEquiv` simply hides `public void Bar` with another `public void Bar`, calling `((IFoo)ref).Bar()` will still invoke the `ImplicitImplEquiv.Bar`. But if the derived class also reinherits `IFoo` and provides a new implementation, the interface vtable will be different than that of `ImplicitImplEquiv`.